# Webpack errors when adding Web3

Tags: gnosis-safe

When I add web3 to my safe app (import the library and create an instance), I get a bunch of errors such as these:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in [...]

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

The other errors are similar, but for `http`, `https`, `crypto` and `os`.
I've tried the suggested fix and variations found through googling, creating a `webpack.config.js` file with a `resolve.fallback` blob, but I continue to get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

web3 needs those node libraries in order to work so you can either:

1. Try ethers.js (I think is not dependent on node modules but not completely sure)
2. Add them using [config-overrides.js](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#2-create-a-config-overridesjs-file-in-the-root-directory)

Example [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react-apps/blob/7e428f1397854d55a36ede6e3b227e5d75be07ef/apps/tx-builder/config-overrides.js#L9)